# Where can I find Windows Delivery Optimization sample code and header files?

Tags: windows

I'm trying to write to Windows Delivery Optimization interfaces, e.g. IDeliveryOptimizationJob2, and can't find the required header files, IDL files, and libraries in the latest Windows 10 SDK.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/delivery_optimization/ideliveryoptimizationjob2

e.g. Header: Deliveryoptimization.h, IDL: DeliveryOptimization.idl, Library: Dosvc.lib, all of these are missing from the SDK.

Has anyone writeen a DO app before, or can point me to some sample code, or to the SDK that contains these header files and libraries?

Comment: Probably available as a Windows Runtime type. Try looking there instead of accessing the raw COM interfaces.

Comment: Hello IInspectable , can you please give me a link where I can look it up? thanks!

Comment: I haven't found those interfaces anywhere either, neither in header files, IDL files, nor .winmd files.